# Check if object is a boolean

Tags: json, glib, rtti, vala

I need to check if my Json.Object is a boolean or not. This is what I've done:

```
var media = root.get_member ("media");
if (!media.get_value_type ().is_a (bool)) {
    this.media.set ("mp4", media.get_object ().get_string_member ("mp4"));
    this.media.set ("webm", media.get_object ().get_string_member ("webm"));
}
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
"media": {
    "mp4": "http:\/\/img-9gag-fun.9cache.com\/photo\/EyVtjpq_460sv.mp4",
    "webm": "http:\/\/img-9gag-fun.9cache.com\/photo\/EyVtjpq_460svwm.webm"
},
```

Or like this if it's a boolean:

```
"media": false,
```

But this condition is not working `!media.get_value_type ().is_a (bool)`, the method `is_a ()` can't take `bool` apparently. How can I check if my value is a boolean or not?

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be this:

```
if (media.get_value_type () != typeof(bool))
```

You can use `typeof ()` to get the `GType` of any data type in Vala and `GType` is what the function returns.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/FAQ#How_do_I_get_the_GType_for_something.3F

https://developer.gnome.org/json-glib/stable/json-glib-JSON-Node.html#json-node-get-value-type

In C you would probably use `G_TYPE_BOOLEAN`:

https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Type-Information.html#G-TYPE-BOOLEAN:CAPS